# Calling main method in Google App Engine module causes 'unable to delete file'-error

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, program-entry-point

In order to avoid going through google endpoints API every time i want to test code changes i use a standard static void main(String args[]).
Whenever i run this method locally from within my GAE module in Android Studio it causes the following error:

> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':backend:appengineExplodeApp'.
>   > Unable to delete file C:\Users\Robert\Documents\AndroidStudioProjects\microservicetestproject2\backend\build\exploded-app\WEB-INF\lib\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.51.jar

This worked earlier but now the mentioned error is showing up.